# Getting positional data of LEO satellites

Tags: gps, satellite, rtklib

How can we get precise lat, long ( or xyz in ECEF ) location of LEO satellite like FORMOSAT (COSMIC-2 ) - including error matrices?

POD data is available [here](https://www.cosmic.ucar.edu/what-we-do/cosmic-2/data), and tried with [‘Level 1a - Precise orbit determination antenna tracking data’](https://data.cosmic.ucar.edu/gnss-ro/cosmic2/nrt/)  with RTKLIB converter but I am getting an error ‘no navigational data’.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: My basic requirement is how to get positional data of a satellite(LEO). sorry for multiple questions.

Comment: Sounds like your last three questions are not adding anything to your first. I think you should [edit] them out.